# Are there any iPhone apps which can display/edit OPML documents?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, software-recommendation, applications

I'm looking to view/edit OPML files on the iPhone/iPad. Is there an app that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CarbonFin](http://carbonfin.com/) and the website https://cfoutliner.appspot.com/ (accessible on any iOS device)

Comment: I second the CarbonFin Outliner suggestion. Basic, functional, useful.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do exactly but since [OPML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPML#Example_OPML_documents) is just another Markup Language you can use any [text editor](http://itunes.apple.com/app/text-editor/id363452079?mt=8) or maybe [one](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id383577124?mt=8) that's also able to highlight XML. You could also try online tools such as google docs, tho I couldn't myself. Here's another way to read only OPML using [iGoogle](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/07/import-opml-files-to-igoogle.html).

I'll also give a shot and guess what kind of OPML you'd be using and suggest [this app](http://appfinder.lisisoft.com/app/outliner-for-ipad.html).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of iOS apps support OPML in different ways. All depends on what you want to do with it.

For editing the actual code, you could use Textastic with its super-nice syntax highlighting. Use the built-in XML syntax definition or easily add your own customized for OPML.

For editing it as a mind-map, check out iThoughts or MindNode.

For working with it in outline form, hey! There's OmniOutliner, CarbonFin or MagicalPad.

And coming soon, but not quite yet, writing app Storyist will be supporting OPML. So you can import that finished outline and use it to start writing your novel, thesis, or crackpot manifesto.

Answer (score 0):

Outline pro is a really good app

Comment: Welcome to the site! We are looking for answers which not only make a recommendation but also explain why/how this application would solve the problem of editing OPML on an iPhone/iPad and why you recommend it. Can you please add some details to your answer?